# Add mouse hover on jqPlot charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

By default when we hover the mouse on any region of the jqplot charts it changes color - that's fine. But I want that on hover it should show its value. For example I have 2 regions on charts as:

1. label=Customer projects,value=20
2. label=POCs,value=10

Now on mouse hover it should show the label as well as the value. For example it should show as

> Customer Projects:20

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack that uses the fact that the labels are just text divs:

```
previousPoint = null;
$('#chartdiv').bind('jqplotDataMouseOver', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) { 
    var labels = $('#chartdiv .jqplot-data-label');
    if (previousPoint != null)
    {
       labels[previousPoint['idx']].innerHTML = previousPoint['data'][1]+'';               
    }
    labels[pointIndex].innerHTML = data[0] + ": " + data[1];
    previousPoint = {'idx':pointIndex, 'data':data};
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/c2PmK/2/).  Remember to cache the jqplot files.

Comment: i have the same requirement as had, i need to show data on mouse hover in barchart, i have implemented the above code, but it was not working, there is error throws at innerhtml data[0], can u tell me what is that **previousPoint = null** , thanks in advance.